# Is there a way to keep the scraped images in python in program memory to tweet out without downloading?

Tags: python, twitter, file-io, python-requests, tweepy

I am scraping image using the requests module in python. I download the file, tweet it out, and instantly delete it. I wanna know if there is anyway to keep the image in program memory to then tweet using the Tweepy library. I printed out the data downloaded and just get a bunch of hex values. I don't wanna create any files, just download, save to a variable, and tweet without the intermittent file creating step.

Comment: Write each image to a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object?.

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy `media_upload` expects either a *filename* or *file* option, the latter allowing for a `File` like object. (https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=update_with_media#tweepy.API.media_upload)

We can achieve this by putting the image data you want into an instance of `io.BytesIO()`

```py
from io import BytesIO

# some code to get image as bytes into variable img

with BytesIO(img) as fd:
    media = API.media_upload(file=fd)
    u,reqresp,resp = Client.create_tweet(...,media_ids=[media.id],...)
```

*Note: This might not be the proper use of the Tweepy API as I have not had any experience with Tweepy directly - just reading through the documentation in the following links to answer your questions on image handling.*

Links:

- https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/entities#media
- https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=update_with_media#tweepy.API.media_upload
- https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_tweet